# Google Apps Script inserts a date to GSheets but changes to undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This code will insert the correct dates in the correct cells, but seems like after each loop (before moving to the next row) the date changes to `undefined`. This only happens for `var = expDelivery` all other dates are fine.

I am not sure why it inserts the date, correctly, then changes to `undefined`.

```js
function doPost(e){
  //append the ID to your spreadsheet like this:
  var sheetID = e.parameter.sheetid;  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var headers = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  
  var uninstalledCol = headers.indexOf("uninstalledDate");
  
  //get all variables passed from app
  var ft = e.parameter.ftNumber;  
  var measuredDate = new Date(e.parameter.measuredDate);
  var installedDate = new Date(e.parameter.installedDate);
  var uninstalledDate = new Date(e.parameter.uninstalledDate);
  //add 21 days to measuredDate 
  var dayInMs = 24*60*60*1000;    //one day in Milliseconds
  var daysToAdd = 21;  
  var expDelivery = new Date(measuredDate.getTime()+(daysToAdd*dayInMs));  
  
  var shtData = sh.getDataRange();
  var shtVals = shtData.getValues();

  var updatedCols = [];
  
  for(var j = 1; j < shtVals.length; j++) //Loop through rows
  {
    for (var i = 6; i < uninstalledCol; i++)  //Loop through columns
    {
      // IF col 1 of current row = ft AND current cell is blank AND current col title = measuredDate AND value passed with same name as col title IS NOT blank
      if(shtVals[j][0] == ft && shtVals[j][i] == "" && headers[i] == "measuredDate" && e.parameter[headers[i]] != "") 
      {
        shtVals[j][i] = e.parameter[headers[i]];
        shtVals[j][i+1] = expDelivery; //Will set the correct date in spreadsheet but changes to "undefined" before moving to next row
        shtData.setValues(shtVals);
        updatedCols.push([headers[i]]);
      } 
      // IF col 1 of current row = ft AND current cell is blank AND current col title IS NOT "DELIVERED DATE" or "measuredDate" AND value passed with same name as col title IS NOT blank
      else if(shtVals[j][0] == ft && shtVals[j][i] == "" && headers[i] != "DELIVERED DATE" && headers[i] != "measuredDate" && e.parameter[headers[i]] != "")
      {
        shtVals[j][i] = e.parameter[headers[i]];
        shtData.setValue(shtVals);
        updatedCols.push([headers[i]]);
      }
    }
  }

 return message(updatedCols);

}


function message(msg) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({Result: msg })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is so inefficient. You're reading sheet values onece here `var shtVals = sh.getDataRange().getValues();`. Then for each row, for each col, you're reading and writing sheet values again and again.

```
for(var j = 1; j < shtVals.length; j++) //Loop through rows
  {
    for (var i = 6; i < uninstalledCol; i++)  //Loop through columns
    {
      {
        // do stuff
      }
      {
        // do stuff
      }
    }
  }
shtData.setValues(data);
```

Reading and writing takes time, that's why you should minimize them as possible. Best way is to read once, do all operation on the values then write once.

There can always be special cases and maybe you don't need speed.

About the issue -

It's writing here `data[j][i+1] = expDelivery;`. This is inside the inner loop which is running a few times, as suggested by the code. The code seems modifying col by col of a row, so it is unlikely for a row to mess with previous row. This is probably inner loop issue where cols are getting read, manipulated and written.

The loop code is not easy to understand, so, fixing bug is harder. You might wanna simplify it first if you haven't fixed the issue already.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm pretty green so still learning the best practices. I've eliminated the `.getValues()` from within the loops. As for the writing to the spreadsheet, because I need the values to go to specific cells, is it possible to do this with a single write function? The part that is giving me trouble when it comes to this, is specifying the range to set values, how do I pass the [j] and [I] values of each entry. I am still working on debugging the date issue, but any help or advice for efficiency would be greatly appreciated also. Thanks again

Comment: You can write just once after the loops

Answer (score 0):

***I need the values to go to specific cells, is it possible to do this with a single write function?***

Yes.

Lets say this is your sheet -

```
    -----------------------------
    | A            | B          |
    -----------------------------
1   | Name         | Age        |
    -----------------------------
2   | Alice        | 25         |
    -----------------------------
3   | Bob          | 30         |
    -----------------------------
```

We do `var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`. We get -

```
values = [ [ Name,  Age ],
           [ Alice,  25 ],
           [ Bob,    30 ] ]
```

Let's say you want to change `A2` into `Jane`. Which indices do you use to access it inside `values` array ?

You can see from sheet, its 2nd row, 1st col. But `values` is a 2-dimensional array, the indices will be 
`values[1][0]` because **indices in arrays start with 0**.

So, the actual indices to access `A2` inside `values` will be `values[1][0]`, **row and col each 1 less than sheet row, col indices**.

Lets change `A2` to `Jane`. `values[1][0] = 'Jane'`

Once you change `values` array, this change is **live, in memory, ready to be accessed in other operation or calculation**. But, it is **not written to sheet yet**.

Lets say you need to change `B2` as `Jane` is `26`. So, do you make that change now ? Or, write previous change into sheet first ? It is preferred to make that change now and write both changes in one operation.

Now, what is the indices in `values` for `B2`?. `B2` is 2nd row, 2nd col in sheet. In `values` array it is `values[1][1]`.

Lets change `B2` to 26. `values[1][1] = 26`. Now both changes are live. If we write `values` into sheet, both changes will be saved.

***The part that is giving me trouble when it comes to this, is specifying the range to set values, how do I pass the [j] and [I] values of each entry.***

Now you know how sheet indices and `values` indices work. Use `values` indices to change/set values on it then write `values` into sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working, and after cleaning up the code, the problem with date is resolved to! Thanks for taking the time to explain everything. You've taught me much.